# Power BI - Incremental Refresh for Datasets

Tags: powerbi

Our Primary Data source for a PowerBI Reports (have a Premium Workspace) is the Delta Tables. The Data is extracted from the Delta Tables via PBI dataflows and Datasets. We are able to set an incremental refresh of the Data Flows where we have seen a drastic reduction in timelines for refreshing an years worth of data instead of needlessly refreshing 10 years of data.

**Basic Flow**

*SRC FILES > DATA BRICKS CODE > DELTA TABLES > PBI DATAFLOWS > PBI DATASETS > POWER BI REPORTS*

However, the Dataset takes about 3 hours to refresh which is very high and this needs to be brought down.

I have tried the below approaches

**1. Partitioning of the Dataset using Tabular Editor -** This converts the Dataset and Report to a Live Connection. This approach is possible if there are no changes to the dataset and all is stable as we will not be able to add any new changes either via Power Queries or Publish new Measures

**2. Partitioning of the Dataset using Transform -** Add parameters such as RangeStart and RangeEnd and then add these parameters to the table in the dataset and use Incremental Refresh in the DataView

**Source: -**
Incremental Refresh Configuration[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/incremental-refresh-configure]

**3. Build 3 Datasets**

- DS1: - Monthly Refresh & Hidden
- DS2: - Daily Refresh & Hidden
- DS: - UNION of DS1 and DS2 and Visible

**Source: -** https://www.thebiccountant.com/2017/01/11/incremental-load-in-powerbi-using-dax-union/

Will the 3rd Option really help in bringing down the Refresh Time for a dataset?

Request your Help here...

Thanks